# Creating a search text box in an Access 2013 Navigation Subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

I created a search text box in Access 2013 that works as in should in the form. When I moved the form to the Navigation form it stopped working. I receive the following error: "The action or method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query." I have changed the condition in the Embedded Macro to read as follows:

```
[conLastName] Like "*" & [Forms]![frmNavigation]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![TxtSearchContacts] & "*"
```

I have also tried:

```
[conLastName] Like "*" & [Forms]![frmNavigation].[NavigationSubform].[Form]![TxtSearchContacts] & "*"
```

And:

```
[conLastName] Like "*" & [Forms]![frmNavigation]![NavigationSubform]![Form]![TxtSearchContacts] & "*"
```

Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated. I have spent well over two hours beating my head against the wall on this one. Thank you. ~Christa

Comment: #1 should work - if NavigationSubform is the name of the subform control on the main form.

Comment: Your error message says your form isn't bound to a data source. from where are you performing this action outside the form?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have built the search into the header of the form. I can get the process to work as a stand alone, but as soon as I place the form in the Navigation form it breaks. That is when I edit the code as above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. NavigationSubform is the name of the subform. I have used this same principle to edit my parameter queries so they work when I move them over into the Navigation form.

Comment: I have moved on and am trying the following:
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()
Me.Filter = "qrySearchContacts" & [conLastName] Like "*" & [Forms]![frmNavigation]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtSearchContacts] & "*"
Me.FilterOn = True 
But the only thing I can get is a blank form. So I am no closer.